# How to delete all the files in a folder including the files in the sub folders without deleting the the folder itself or any of its sub folders

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete all the files contained in a folder. The code I am using deletes all the files in the root folder but it does not delete the files inside the sub folders. Here  is the code:

```
If Not Directory.Exists("C:\New Folder") Then
   Return
End If

Dim files() As String
files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("C:\New Folder")

For Each element As String In files
   If (Not Directory.Exists(element)) Then
      File.Delete(Path.Combine("C:\New Folder", Path.GetFileName(element)))
   End If
Next
```

**What I want here is:**

> I want to delete all the files inside the folder “New Folder”. At the
>   same time, I want to keep the sub folders and delete all the files it
>   contains. So, after the operation, “New Folder” may have any number of
>   sub folders but it should not have even a single file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this recursive sub

```
 Sub DeleteFilesFromFolder(Folder As String)
    If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
        For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder)
            File.Delete(_file)
        Next
        For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)

            DeleteFilesFromFolder(_folder)
        Next

    End If

End Sub

'Somewhere you call

DeleteFilesFromFolder("C:\New Folder")
```

Comment: Thanks Nizam, This is the solution I was looking for.