# VB.Net Delete all files in folder

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to delete all files from single folder in VB.Net but to keep that folder.

As far as i know, i can delete files by this way:

```
Dim heart17 As System.IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo("path")
heart17.Delete()
```

And it works, but i need to empty a whole folder.

The folder path is

> `C:\Users\username\Desktop\Games`.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221181/how-to-delete-all-the-files-in-a-folder-including-the-files-in-the-sub-folders-w), but it doesn't work for me (it has some errors or i did something wrong).

Comment: the answer of the question you put the link works well, what's the error message displayed

Comment: you need to Imports System.IO

Comment: Yeah, i did it and it works (with few changes).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will help you to [delete all files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) in the specified directory you can specify the search pattern to delete files that satisfies the pattern; some possible search patterns are:

- `"*.jpg"` - selects all `jpg` files.
- `"*.txt"` - selects all text files.
- `"*123.txt"` selects all text files whose name ends with `123`

  ```
  Dim directoryName As String = "your path here"
  For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName ,"*.*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
      File.Delete(deleteFile)
  Next
  ```

Comment: Before i say anything, you have error in code (you need ")" after TopDirectoryOnly). The errors are: "SearchOption' is not declared" and "GetFiles' is not a member of 'System.IO.FileInfo".

Comment: you need to Imports `System.IO`

Comment: Yeah, it works now. Only mistake you made is that you can't dim "directory", so i changed it to "directory1" and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
FileSystem.Kill ("c:\path\*.*")
FileSystem.Kill ("c:\path\*.jpg")
```

etc.?

Comment: This triggers an error if no files are found inside the folder path.

Answer (score 1):

IO.Directory.Delete(

"true" means blow everything away:  all sub-dirs. and files

Comment: Yes, but this deletes the folder itself too and the question is to delete the files inside.